# injective/path component

Tags: general-topology

[image]

For $f$ to be injective it'll have to be one to one, so could i somehow create a field $X$ which is one to one, however have it so somehow the path component for $X$ is $2$ and the path components for $Y$ is $1$?

Would this answer my question if yes could someone give an example of how i would create this?

Comment: Can you think of a disconnected set that is contained in a connected set?

Comment: would $[0,1]$ be disconnected within $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @smith: The unit interval is path connected within the reals.

Comment: I think you need to examine the definitions and examples of disconnected/connected sets.

Comment: my knowledge of topology is very limited at the moment, in order for it to be not connected it needs to have non trivial clopen sets?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Think about the discrete $2$-point set $\{0,1\}\subseteq [0,1]$ and the identity map.

Comment: could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: @smith: What are the clopen sets of the discrete $2$-point set? What about the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: all points within the 2-point set would be clopen as it is discrete... whereas in the interval $[0,1]$ the only clopen sets would be the whole set and the empty set?

Comment: @smith: Exactly. So what are $\pi_0(\{0,1\})$ and $\pi_0([0,1])$? Now note that any map defined on a discrete set is continuous. The only injective ones is the identity map and the permutation map. Take the identity map for example. What must the induced map $f_*$ be? And why?

Comment: it makes sense that the discrete map is now continuous and injective and therefore the induced map would be surjective? i tend to get slightly confused when it comes to the induced map

Comment: @smith: Once you know what $\pi_0(\{0,1\})$ and $\pi_0([0,1])$ are in this particular case, you will realize that there will only exist one map from the first to the latter. This must precisely be the induced map: you don't even need to calculate it explicitly.

Comment: I dont fully understand ... $\pi_0(\{0,1\})$ would be the path components of our discrete set, which is disjoint? and hence is equal to $2$?? and the path component for $\pi_0([0,1])$ is $1$?

Comment: i get that this shows our discrete map is injective but how does this show our induced map in not?

Comment: @smith: So you have concluded that $\pi_0(\{0,1\})$ is a $2$-point set, and $\pi_0([0,1])$ is a $1$-point set. Now, there is only $1$ map from a $2$-point set to a $1$-point set. What is it? Is it injective?